# How to add older office Compatibility to PHPExcel_Writer_CSV

Tags: php, csv, phpexcel

[image: 2007 vs 2002 version]
2007 vs 2002 version

For **PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007** this method is working, but for **PHPExcel_Writer_CSV** returns this error. And the file is not well formated in older version

```
  Fatal error:
 Call to undefined method PHPExcel_Writer_CSV::setOffice2003Compatibility()
```

And this is the code I use

```
  $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_CSV($objPHPExcel);
  $objWriter->setDelimiter(',');
  $objWriter->setEnclosure('');
  $objWriter->setLineEnding("\r\n");
  $objWriter->setSheetIndex(0);
```

Comment: A CSV file has no formatting. The CSV writer does not need this method.

Comment: What do you mean by "not well formated in older version"?

Comment: That's nothing to do with compatibility.... the file is perfectly well formed and valid as a CSV file. Open it in a text editor, and you'll see. However, when opening that file in MS Excel itself, the value separator used in a CSV file is locale-specific for MS Excel. For locales where a `,` is used as a decimal separator, then a `;` will be used as a value separator; otherwise a comma will normally be used. The CSV Writer provides all the methods for defining the separator that you wish to use

Comment: Try using the writer's setDelimiter() method to set the delimiter to a `;` rather than a `,`

Comment: Now in 2007 version is the same as 2002 .. its bad

Comment: Open the CSV file in a __text editor__ and see if it's correct in that... and perhaps try setting the enclosure to a `"`. (unsure why you disabled the enclosure anyway)

Comment: enclosure is set to '' alredy and in the text editor is correct

Comment: `$objWriter->setEnclosure('');` in your code suggests that enclosure isn't set to `"`

Comment: Try using a "\t" separator rather than `,` or `;` then. If it's correct in a text editor, then the problem is with MS Excel, not with PHPexcel's file generation

Comment: "\t" also dosent work but ':' is fine still there is formating but the ean number is full

Comment: When MS Excel opens a CSV file, it doesn't just read the contents but manipulates it as well, so an unquoted value that contains a numeric value such as `00123` will be converted to a number (123); whereas if that value is quoted ("00123"), it will be treated as a string and retain its leading zeroes. The same applies to larger numeric values which will be converted to float (and potentially displayed in scientific format if they are larger values), whereas if they are quoted, the full value will be retained as a string

Answer (score 1):

Office 2003 compatibility is meaningless for a CSV file.

Office 2003 Compatibility relates to style elements that changed in the OfficeOpenXML file format between MS Excel 2007 and MS Excel 2003 with the compatibility pack. CSV files do not contain any style or format information, so the principle of Office 2003 compatibility for a CSV file is meaningless.

A CSV file is a CSV file irrespective of which versions of MS Excel you use to open it

Comment: I add an image to see what i mean